# Is there a way to test hidden divs in this component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using jest and typescript. In my component there is a part that on first load of component which is hidden because of an usestate. after a function running in our app it's state becomes true and hidden div becomes visible.

I want to write 100% line coverage for this component but it seems i cant mock the usestate what im doing wrong?

here is the minimalized component(i removed unused parts to make more readable):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, FC } from 'react'
import EmailEditor from 'react-email-editor'
import CustomButton from '../customButton/CustomButton'

type ICustomEmailEditor = {
  customClass?: string
  setFieldValue?: any
  json?: any
  jsonTemplate?: string
}

const CustomEmailEditor: FC<ICustomEmailEditor> = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const emailEditorRef = useRef(null)
  const [isEditorLoading, setIsEditorLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [previewText, setPreviewText] = useState<string>(t('CAMPAIGN.SHOW_PREVIEW'))

  const onReady = () => {
    emailEditorRef.current.addEventListener('design:updated', async (data: Event) => {
      const value: any = await exportHtml('save')
      props.setFieldValue('message', value.html)
      props.setFieldValue('json_template', JSON.stringify(value.design))
    })
    setIsEditorLoading(false)
  }


  return (
    <div className="email-container">
      {!isEditorLoading ? (
        <div className="email-buttons-wrapper">
          <CustomButton
            type="button"
            holder={t('CAMPAIGN.EXPORT_HTML')}
        
          />
          <CustomButton type="button" holder={previewText}  />
        </div>
      ) : null}
      <EmailEditor ref={emailEditorRef} onReady={onReady} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomEmailEditor
```

email editor is irrelevant because there are other line coverage tests for rest of the project that i'm struggling with that uses usestate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an async test, where you
`await waitFor(() => {getElementsByClassName("email-buttons-wrapper").toBeInTheDocument()})`

I cant remember the syntax exactly, but react testing docs will help you out there.

If the EmailEditor will load in eventually, then it should trigger the onReady function and show your div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i've tried ur solution but dint work also, i want to learn how to change the state via testing because this is just an another example. There are lots of state dependant rendered components.